# How to convert equation to vector (matrix) form?

Tags: matrix

How can I **convert** expression `a1*u1+a2*u2+a3*u3` to the vector form of dot product `A.U`, where `A={a1,a2,a3}` and `U={u1,u2,u3}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define :

```
expr=a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*u3;
aVec={a1, a2, a3};
```

then you can get

```
uVec=Coefficient[expr, aVec];

Dot[aVec, uVec]==expr
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you may try

```
vec={u1,u2,u3};
covec=(Normal@CoefficientArrays[a1*u1+a2*u2+a3*u3,vec])//Last
```

> {a1, a2, a3}

where we get

```
covec.vec
```

> a1 u1 + a2 u2 + a3 u3

This also works for system of equations.

```
{const, coeff} = Normal@
 CoefficientArrays[{
 a + x - y - z == 0, 
 b + x + 2 y + z == 0
 }, {x, y, z}];
 coeff. {x, y, z} + const
```

> {a + x - y - z, b + x + 2 y + z}

See the important matrix

```
MatrixForm[coeff]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to interpret your question, but here goes.

You can separate the components of `(a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*u3)` into two vectors by the following:

```
vecs = Transpose[List @@@ (List @@ (a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*u3))]
```

> {{a1, a2, a3}, {u1, u2, u3}}

The dot product can be formed:

```
Dot@@vecs
```

> a1 u1 + a2 u2 + a3 u3

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (similar to image_doctor's) uses replacement rules rather than Apply. Observe that the internal representation is

```
 FullForm[a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*u3]
```

> Plus[Times[a1,u1],Times[a2,u2],Times[a3,u3]]

If we were to change the "Times" to "List" and change "Plus" to "List" then we'd be almost there:

```
prod=a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*u3 //. {Times -> List, Plus -> List}
```

> {{a1,u1},{a2,u2},{a3,u3}}

All we need do is pick out the a's and u's separately. So we could define:

```
a = prod[[All, 1]];
u = prod[[All, 2]];
```

Then Dot[a, u] gives the original product.